# Render field by name in custom content node template

Tags: nodes, entities

I'm trying to create a custom node template in drupal 8.

I've added the content type and am displaying them in the Front Page view.

I would like to render each field in the in the the node template (node--content-type.html.twig).

Using the recommended {{ content.field_name }} syntax, causes the node to print nothing except the title.

Are there any prerequisites to using this syntax, what am I missing here?

Comment: Did you create that content type by UI or by your own module? I you did it by module, you need to fill the content array by yourself.

Comment: Use the correct machine name of the field, If Title is working means machine name must be a problem. Please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up installing a fresh copy of Drupal and re-adding the content type (through the UI as before). After that it worked fine.

Not sure why that happened, no time to debug, will just continue with this install.

I suspect either I broke the the 'Frontpage' view while fiddling, or one of the Modules was breaking it, perhaps [Twig Field Value](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value).

I need to now access a multi value field in Twig, thinking something like {{ content.field_name.0 }}. I need to access the array directly without the use of a foreach loop, because they fit into different parts of the html layout.

Thanks for the responses!